# Change method to return two dictionaries with Tuple

Tags: c#

Hello i have a method that returns a

```
Dictionary<Text, List<string>>
```

I want it to return two **Dictionary**.

This is my method :

```
public static Dictionary<Text, List<string>> CotisationURSSAF(TnsPrimitiveSession primitiveSession, int _IndexEnCours, CTNSExercice _Exercice, bool isAjustee)
     {

         Dictionary<Text, List<string>> CotisationURSSAF = new Dictionary<Text, List<string>>();

         Dictionary<Text, List<string>> ElementsPrisEnCompte = new Dictionary<Text, List<string>>();

         return CotisationURSSAF;

       }
```

What i have tried is to use **Tuple** but i still have problems my code is wrong :

```
  public Tuple<Dictionary<Text, List<string>, Text, List<string>>, Dictionary<Dictionary<Text, List<string>, Text, List<string>>> CotisationURSSAF<Text, List<string>, Text, List<string>>((TnsPrimitiveSession primitiveSession, int _IndexEnCours, CTNSExercice _Exercice, bool isAjustee))
        {

         Dictionary<Text, List<string>> CotisationURSSAF = new Dictionary<Text, List<string>>();

         Dictionary<Text, List<string>> ElementsPrisEnCompte = new Dictionary<Text, List<string>>();

        return Tuple.Create(CotisationURSSAF, ElementsPrisEnCompte);

       }
```

Comment: You've got a little lost there... try `public Tuple<Dictionary<Text, List<string>>, Dictionary<Text, List<string>>> CotisationURSSAF...`

Comment: please don't use snippets for C#. Use code blocks

Comment: Instead of this generic tuple monster, why don't you simply return a `Dictionary<Text, List<string>>[]` with two items?

Comment: Forget the Tuple, build yourself a class to hold the dictionaries, it'll be much more straight forward

Comment: That return type is ridiculous `Tuple<Dictionary<Text, List<string>, Text, List<string>>, Dictionary<Dictionary<Text, List<string>, Text, List<string>>> CotisationURSSAF<Text, List<string>, Text, List<string>>`

Comment: Sounds to me that the method might be doing much and violates the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @PeterBons: it's single responsibility is to create type monsters

Comment: LMAO @TimSchmelter `var x = new TupleMonsterFactory(); //grrrr`

Comment: I was that close to downvote when I readed "CotisationURSSAF". ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two better ways instead of this weird tuple monster that no one can understand:

1. use a custom class with two properties, both of type `Dictionary<Text, List<string>>`
2. return an array with two items: `Dictionary<Text, List<string>>[]`

---

```
public static Dictionary<Text, List<string>>[] CotisationURSSAF(TnsPrimitiveSession primitiveSession, int _IndexEnCours, CTNSExercice _Exercice, bool isAjustee)
{
     Dictionary<Text, List<string>> CotisationURSSAF = new Dictionary<Text, List<string>>();
     Dictionary<Text, List<string>> ElementsPrisEnCompte = new Dictionary<Text, List<string>>();
     return new[]{ CotisationURSSAF, ElementsPrisEnCompte };
}
```

You can acccess them via index.

Comment: okey now how i call this method in my view just to get the first item of dictionary this is what i did (   Dictionary<Text, List<string>> notificationsURSSAF = WebTns3.Repository.TnsRepositoryExercice.CotisationURSSAF(this.PrimitiveSession, _iIndexEnCours, _Exercice, false); )

Comment: @mecabpazzo95: just store this array in a variable and then access the `CotisationURSSAF` via `array[0]` and the `ElementsPrisEnCompte` dictionary via `array[1]`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter how to store it in a variable and then call it with index in my view

Comment: @mecabpazzo95: `var bothDict=WebTns3.Repository.TnsRepositoryExercice.CotisationURSSA(...);` Now access both dictionaries: `var first=bothDict[0]; var second=bothDict[1];`

Answer (score 3):

```
Tuple<
      Dictionary<Text, List<string>>,
      Dictionary<Text, List<string>>
     >
```

Feel free to remove linebreaks.

However, if it was hard to create, it will be hard to read. Maybe you should put them in a class of their own for better readability.

Answer (score 3):

Bonjour, a solution: return an array of `Dictionary`, you can then access by array[0] & array[1]

```
public static Dictionary<Text, List<string>>[] CotisationURSSAF(TnsPrimitiveSession primitiveSession, int _IndexEnCours, CTNSExercice _Exercice, bool isAjustee)
{
    var list = new List<Dictionary<Text, List<string>>>();    
    Dictionary<Text, List<string>> CotisationURSSAF = new Dictionary<Text, List<string>>();    
    Dictionary<Text, List<string>> ElementsPrisEnCompte = new Dictionary<Text, List<string>>();    
    list.Add(CotisationURSSAF);
    list.Add(ElementsPrisEnCompte);   
    return list.ToArray();       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method type has to match your return type. You are defining a Dictionary, that is 4 generic data types when Dictionary only accepts 2.

A Tuple is another construct that accepts two (or more) generic data types.

So what you really want to do is return a Tuple with two Dictionaries as defined in your method:

```
Tuple<Dictionary<Text, List<string>>, Dictionary<Text, List<string>>>
```

Seems like you should look into generics a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a class instead of a tuple. It makes things much more apparent to the caller. For example:

```
    public class ReturnModel
    {
        public Dictionary<Text, List<string>> CotisationURSSAF { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<Text, List<string>> ElementsPrisEnCompte { get; set; }

        public ReturnModel(Dictionary<Text, List<string>> cotisationURSSAF, Dictionary<Text, List<string>> elementsPrisEnCompte)
        {
            this.CotisationURSSAF = cotisationURSSAF;
            this.ElementsPrisEnCompte = elementsPrisEnCompte;
        }
    }
```

And your method returns this model. (Rename it to your business case)

Happy Coding!

Comment: Be wary if constructors that require properties. This makes you class very inflexible for no benefit, you can just as easy do `new ReturnModel() {CotisationURSSAF =..};`, this is more flexible and just as easy to create